# How to make popup window on that shows values of x and y axis

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

As shown in this Line Chart [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCEBi.png). How to make popup window on that shows values of x and y axis.When ever i touch the nodes in line chart i want display the popup window on respective position with respective X,Y values. Like in above image link.

```
final LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    XAxis xl = lineChart.getXAxis();
    xl.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new Entry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new Entry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new Entry(6f, 2));
    entries.add(new Entry(2f, 3));
    entries.add(new Entry(18f, 4));
    entries.add(new Entry(9f, 5));

    final LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries , "y-axies");
    // creating labels
    final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");

    LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset);
    lineChart.setData(data); // set the data and list of lables into chart
    lineChart.setDescription("Description");  // set the description
    dataset.setDrawCubic(true);
    dataset.setDrawFilled(true);
    dataset.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    lineChart.animateY(5000);
```

Comment: what problem are you facing ...

Comment: welcome to SOF dear!!! @Bhagya Shri

Comment: you want to show a line chart in popup window???

Answer (score 0):

If you use MPAndroidChart library, you could achieve this using native MarkerView class. Description you can find in wiki on Github hosted project.

Edit:
I add some info, how we can achieve that:
1. You must implement MarkerView class, that enable draw popups on charts. Example class:

```
public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerView {

private TextView tvContent;

public CustomMarkerView (Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);
    // this markerview only displays a textview
    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
    tvContent.setText("" + e.getVal()); // set the entry-value as the display text
}

@Override
public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
    // this will center the marker-view horizontally
    return -(getWidth() / 2);
}

@Override
public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
    // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
    return -getHeight();
}
```

2. If you have this, next you must define xml file with layout of your popup. Example xml:

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/markerImage" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</RelativeLayout>`

3. After that you must only attach you custom class to chartView:

`CustomMarkerView mv = new CustomMarkerView(Context, R.layout.custom_marker_view_layout);
chart.setMarkerView(mv);`

After that you will have full functional popups on your chart. Link to website with further information: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14054890)

Comment: As you suggest, I add example of implementation. Don't vote down.